# Not enough arguements for perl module-Compilation error

Tags: perl, perl-module

Hi I have a Perl script named `feed_validator.pl`. From this, I am calling a Perl module named `fetch_sequence_vals.pm` as follows:

```
my ($AIT_hash_ref,$SE_hash_ref,$SBC_hash_ref,$db_pack_val_tpb)=fetch_sequneceVals::seqVals();
```

`fetch_sequence_vals.pm` returns the reference of three hashes as shown below.

```
return(\%AIT_hash,\%SE_hash,\%SBC_hash,$db_pack_val_tpb);
```

Now, I am passing these three hashes as input for two Perl modules named `SortFeedSeq` and `SeqComparator`, as shown below.

```
my $sortfeedtrailer = SortFeedSeq::sortfeedseq(
    $region,$sortfileout,$SortedTrailerFile,\%AIT_hash,\%SE_hash,\%SBC_hash);   
my $compareseq= SeqComparator::comparator(
    $region,$SortedTrailerFile,$seq_err,$gap_err,\%AIT_hash,\%SE_hash,\%SBC_hash);
```

When I run `feed_validator.pl`, it's throwing a compilation error saying

```
Not enough arguments for SortFeedSeq::sortfeedseq
```

and

```
Not enough arguments for SeqComparator::comparator
```

I am stuck in this from few days. Kindly someone help me in solving the error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: They are the subroutines inside SortFeedSeq and SeqComparator package respectively.

Comment: Not the problem you're asking about, but shouldn't `\%AIT_hash,\%SE_hash,\%SBC_hash` be `$AIT_hash_ref,$SE_hash_ref,$SBC_hash_ref`? Always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`!

Comment: Hi I am a beginner in perl. What exactly a prototype mean. How to find it out?

Comment: 'sub sortfeedseq($$$$$$){ my $feed_type=$_[0];
 my $FeedInputFile=$_[1];
 my $SortedTrailerFile=$_[2];
 my $AIT_hash_ref=$_[3];
 my $SE_hash_ref=$_[4];
 my $SBC_hash_ref=$_[5];
my code......}'

Comment: sub comparator($$$$$$$) {my $feed_type=$_[0];
    my $InputSortedFile=$_[1];
 my $Seqerrfile=$_[2];
 warn info_H. "Seqerrfile is:$Seqerrfile \n"; 
 my $Gaperrfile=$_[3];
 warn info_H. "Gaperrfile is:$Seqerrfile \n";
 my $AIT_hash_ref=$_[4];
 my $SE_hash_ref=$_[5];
 my $SBC_hash_ref=$_[6];
}

Comment: This is how I am reading the arguments in subroutines.

Comment: 1) That's not readable. Pieces of your question should be in your Question. 2) The code in your question combined with those definitions do not result in the error messages you got.

Comment: it's saying the error in in line num 92 and 93. in line 92 and 93 I am not calling these subroutines. line 92 and 93 is below code 
my %SBC_hash=%$SBC_hash_ref;
my $extractfooter = ExtractSort::extractfooter("$feedDir/$_",$fileout);

Answer (score 1):

`sortfeedseq` and `comparator` each have a prototype. A sub's prototype dictates the syntax of calls to it, and you are violating the syntax imposed by the prototypes of these subs. Specifically, you aren't passing the correct number of arguments to the subs.

As we aren't familiar with the subs in question, we can't tell you what the expect for arguments. You'll have to consult the documentation for these modules, or study the subs themselves.